# Why do four local arrays larger than 63000 elements result in a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define DATA_SIZE 65000


int main()
{
     int a[DATA_SIZE],b[DATA_SIZE],c[DATA_SIZE],d[DATA_SIZE];
     for(int i=0;i<DATA_SIZE;i++)
     {
         a[i]=i;
         b[i]=i;
         c[i]=i;
      }
     for(int j=0;j<DATA_SIZE;j++)
     {
         d[i]=a[i]+b[i]+c[i];

     }
     return 0;
}
```

This program gives a stack overflow error, If I increase the value of `DATA_SIZE` beyond 63000. Why it is happening in this program?

If I want to use the value of variable `i` more than 2 lakh, how can I achieve this?

thanks

Comment: That's not a complete, or even working program. That can't give stack overflow.

Comment: this was edited after i got the solution........

Comment: please read comment in reply to alok save, which  i gave it in next answer

Comment: @icepack: Please do not edit Qs/tags in a way which changes the context of the  original Q and the answers to it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Why it would *not* give stackoverflow? How you can guarantee such thing?

Comment: @Ajay It can _now_, but not when I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably creating those huge sized arrays locally and thus running out of stack space since it is limited.

There are a few options to choose from:

- Use a `std::vector` or
- Declare them as global or static or
- Use dynamic memory allocation using `new` and `delete`.

If you do use the last option make sure you use RAII through smart pointers and not raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` is 4 bytes in size on most systems.  Each of the four arrays is 65000 `int` elements, thus using `65000 * sizeof(int) = 260000` bytes.  Collectively, the four arrays are using a total of `260000 * 4 = 1040000` bytes of stack space.  That is dangerously close to the 1MB default stack size used by many linkers (you can change the default stack size in your project configuration).  That is why you get an overflow if you try to increase the size of your arrays - you are indeed exceeding the stack size configured at link-time.

If you want to use large amounts of memory, use the heap instead of the stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define DATA_SIZE 65000

int main()
{
     int *a = new int[DATA_SIZE];
     int *b = new int[DATA_SIZE];
     int *c = new int[DATA_SIZE];
     int *d = new int[DATA_SIZE];

     for(int i=0;i<DATA_SIZE;i++)
     {
         a[i]=i;
         b[i]=i;
         c[i]=i;
     }

     for(int j=0;j<DATA_SIZE;j++)
     {
         d[i]=a[i]+b[i]+c[i];
     }

     delete[] a;
     delete[] b;
     delete[] c;
     delete[] d;

     return 0;
}
```

Which can then be changed to use the `std::vector` class to manage the heap memory for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#define DATA_SIZE 65000

int main()
{
     std::vector<int> a(DATA_SIZE);
     std::vector<int> b(DATA_SIZE);
     std::vector<int> c(DATA_SIZE);
     std::vector<int> d(DATA_SIZE);

     for(int i=0;i<DATA_SIZE;i++)
     {
         a[i]=i;
         b[i]=i;
         c[i]=i;
     }

     for(int j=0;j<DATA_SIZE;j++)
     {
         d[i]=a[i]+b[i]+c[i];
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're allocating way too many variables to the call stack. I recommend allocating to the heap if you intend on having huge arrays like that.

You can do so with pointers.